# Want to build a embedded link to open pdf in web view

Tags: google-docs

I want to build an application that opens pdf in web view. For that i need a embedded link of google docs. The link should be like this https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded = true&url. But I am not able to make it cam someone tell how can I make it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  I have removed the incorrect tag "embedded" from your post.  When you type a tag a description appears which shows what it is for, so please take care when adding tags in future. "embedded" is for embedded microcontrollers etc, not embedding links.

Comment: From where I can make such a link I am making links from Google docs but I am not able to make one in Google docs

Comment: I have google docs but am not able to make links of this kind https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OQXxDQF-cujiSBMnvWT0QTuXApOgg7a4/view?usp=sharing. i want to make a link http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf&embedded=true like this. please guide me through how can i make a link of the latter type

Comment: Please guide me through how can i make a link http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf&embedded=true of this type in google docs